# Слитно или раздельно писать слово с "не"

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, частица-не

Слитно или раздельно надо писать слово с *не* в следующем предложении? *Ни одно обращение в МФЦ не останется (не)доведенным до логического конца.*

Answer (score 2):

С полными формами причастий отрицание *не* пишется раздельно, если при них имеются зависимые слова ([Лопатин, § 150](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=76))

**Ни одно обращение в МФЦ не останется не доведенным до логического конца.**